# Checkbox state change in activity

Tags: android, custom-adapter, android-checkbox

I am trying to change the state of a `CheckBox` (which is being placed inside a `ListView` with a custom Adapter) from the activity.  Is that even possible?

I am trying to get the `View` of the `CheckBox` using it's tag but it is returning null.

```
            View v = new View(this);
            ck = (CheckBox) v.findViewWithTag(tag); //Here ck is null
            ck.setChecked(true);
```

**Update** for code:

*OnCreate()*

```
{
    ....
    populateListView(id);
    ....
}

private void populateListView(int id)
{
    String errorDescriptionQuery = "SELECT error_description FROM " + TABLE_ERROR + " JOIN " + TABLE_REPAIR_ERROR + " ON " +
                                                TABLE_REPAIR_ERROR + ".error_id = " + TABLE_ERROR + "._id" +
                                                " WHERE " + TABLE_REPAIR_ERROR + ".repair_id = " + id;

    errorList = new ArrayList<Error>();

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(errorDescriptionQuery, null);

    if(c.getCount() > 1)
    {
        c.moveToFirst();
        do
        {
            Error e = new Error();
            e.setDescription(c.getString(0));
            e.setChecked(false);
            errorList.add(e);
        }
        while(c.moveToNext());
    }
    else if(c.getCount() == 1)
    {
        c.moveToFirst();

        Error e = new Error();
        e.setDescription(c.getString(0));
        e.setChecked(false);
        errorList.add(e);
    }
    else
    {
        //Exception - no errors found with that id.
    }
    while(c.moveToNext());

    adapter = new RepairErrorListChkBoxAdapter(this, R.layout.repairerrorcontent, errorList, passedID);
    lvError.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

*Custom adapter*

```
public class RepairErrorListChkBoxAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
String TABLE_ERROR = "tbl_Error";
String TABLE_MATERIAL = "tbl_Material";

DatabaseImplementation myDB;
SQLiteDatabase db;

private ArrayList<String> materialList;

ViewHolder holder;
int testcount = 0;
public ArrayList<Error> list;
private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater mInflator;
private int repairID;
boolean moreThanOne;

public RepairErrorListChkBoxAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Error> list, int repairID)
{
    this.mContext = context;
    this.list = list;
    this.repairID = repairID;

    this.materialList = new ArrayList<String>();

    myDB = new DatabaseImplementation(this.mContext);
    db = myDB.getWritableDatabase();

    mInflator = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() 
{
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) 
{
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{   
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.repairerrorcontent, null);

        //holder.text = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtErrorDesc);
        holder.chk = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkSelected);
        holder.chk.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener(holder.chk));

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.chk.setText("  " + list.get(position).getDescription());
    holder.chk.setClickable(true);
    holder.chk.setFocusable(true);
    holder.chk.setTag(testcount);

    if(list.get(position).isChecked() == true)
    {
        holder.chk.setChecked(true);
    }
    else
    {
        holder.chk.setChecked(false);
    }

    String materialNameQuery = "SELECT material_name FROM " + TABLE_MATERIAL + ";";

    Cursor getMaterialName = db.rawQuery(materialNameQuery, null);
    getMaterialName.moveToFirst();
    do
    {
        materialList.add(getMaterialName.getString(0));
    }
    while(getMaterialName.moveToNext());

    return convertView;
}

public void changeCheckBoxState(String tag)
{

}

private class MyClickListener implements OnClickListener
{
    CheckBox checkbox = null;

    public MyClickListener(CheckBox cb)
    {
        checkbox = cb;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) 
    {

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setTitle("Materials");
        builder.setMessage("Did you require any materials to fix this error?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                v.setTag("clickedBox");
                CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(mContext);
                cb = (CheckBox) v;
                String clickedError;
                clickedError = cb.getText().toString() ;
                String tag =  (String) v.getTag();

                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Material.class);
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("materialList", materialList);
                intent.putExtra("clickedError", clickedError);
                intent.putExtra("repairID", repairID);
                intent.putExtra("tag", tag);
                ((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(intent, 1);            
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {
                if(checkbox.getTag() == v.getTag())
                {
                    checkbox.setChecked(true);
                }
            }               
        });
        builder.show();
    }   
}

static class ViewHolder
{
    CheckBox chk;
}

}
```

Comment: http://lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html

Comment: @LalitPoptani THanks for answering.  It is not a recycling problem.  I just need to set a checkbox to checked from the activity.  Is there a way to save all the CheckBoxes added by the adapter to a List from the activity?

Comment: that post includes your queries answer also :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself.

I had a previous `ArrayList` containing all the text that will be presented by each `checkbox`.  I used that `ArrayList` to compare the value of the clicked `checkbox`, and than re-created the adapter for the `listview` with the updated list.

Thank you all for the help.

```
for(Error temp : errorList)
            {
                if(temp.getDescription().equals(clicked))
                {
                    temp.setChecked(true);
                }
            }
            adapter = new RepairErrorListChkBoxAdapter(this, R.layout.repairerrorcontent, errorList, passedID);
            lvError.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
View rowView = listView.getChildAt(viewID);
  if(rowView != null)
  {
     // do whatever you want here
     ck = (CheckBox) v.findViewWithTag(tag);
     ck.setChecked(true);
  }
```

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.  You can only implement that in the custom adapter class right?  I need to setChecked from the activity not the adapter class.

Comment: you can get it from activity class also if your activity has listview.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
for(int i=0; i < mListViewObject.getChildCount(); i++){
    RelativeLayout itemLayout = (RelativeLayout)mListViewObject.getChildAt(i);
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    cb.setChecked(true);
}
```

mListViewObject is your list view object

Above code works in Activity not adapter. i am using it.

Update RelativeLayout with the layout you are using for listview in above code

Comment: Nice approach.  Tried it and somehow lvError.getChildCount() is 0.  I have 4 items inside.

Comment: friend this code is working fine for me. This is exact copy, i think some thing else is the problem. Just check yourcode once. Where are you adding above code

Comment: in the activity's onActivityResult().  Because I need to do the above based on the result of another activity.

Comment: add the code of creating listview object, also check after inserting the data count of listview object is it still 0

Comment: Yes I just checked that.  After setting the adapter and populating the listview, the count is still 0.

Comment: it means problem is with listview object. i need to check the listview  object how it is created in activity. could you please share the code for it. if it contain confidential information rename the variables, methods and class names

Comment: Updating the original post now.  Nothing is confidential do not worry

Comment: definition and initialization of lvError is not present in shared code. Please add that part as well